# .NET Embedded/Offline DB that works with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, local

I've been researching different solutions for an offline database.
Basically I have a desktop application and I would like it to communicate with a database, without requiring internet connection. So I am looking for a way to ship my app along with a database that the app can work with.

All my DB intercation will happen through Entity Framework, so I need a solution that is compatible with it. So far, I have always used SQL Server Express for my DB, but as far as I know that requires that SQL Server is installed on the user's machine, which is obviously not what I need.

My DB will not need to handle huge amounts of data. (Worst-case would be something around `100,000 - 1,000,000` rows of data in the DB).

From what I am reading I found that SQLite, and SQL Server CE and a feature of SQL Server called LocalDB might do the job for me. (SQL Server CE is no longer supported my Microsoft, so I am guessing its not a good idea)

I was wondering if I am on the right track here? Is this the way to go, or is there a way to embed my SQL Server Express into my app.

Comment: local DB would be the option for you. Since your requirement is is limited ti maximum of 1m rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact and SQLite can both run as embedded and work with EF (SQL Ce much better than SQLite)

LocalDB might also be an option, requires admin access to install (not during runtime)